# Using Azure translator to translate text from Japanese to English but failing with error '400003'

Tags: python, azure, translation

I have been exploring the Azure cognitive services of text translator to translate text from one origin to the other. In my case I want to translate Japanese text into English.

I have followed the documentation and utilized the python code to achieve the above task. However I received an error while getting the response from the API.

> Error code:400003
>   Message: One of the language specified is not valid.

Didn't find much help on the error code. Attaching the code for reference. Any suggestions/workarounds will be helpful.

```py
    import os, requests, uuid, json
     key_var_name =subscription_key
     endpoint_var_name =endpoint_details_of_API
     path = '/transliterate?api-version=3.0'
     params = '&to=en'
     constructed_url = endpoint_var_name + path + params
     headers = {
     'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':subscription_key',
     'Content-type': 'application/json',
     'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': 'eastasia',
     'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
      }
      body =[{
      'text': 'こんにちは'
      }]
      request=requests.post(constructed_url,headers=headers,json=body)
      response=request.json()
      print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in translation and transliteration, and also in the way you call the respective APIs.

Since you are using the Transliteration API, you need to specify the script you would like to transliterate to/from.

- The **language code** for Japanese is `ja`
- The **script** for Japanese is `Jpan`
- The **language code** for English is `en`
- The **script** for Latin is `Latn`

More info: [Language and region support for Translator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/language-support).

Constructing the URL of the API in python should look something like this:

```py
path = '/transliterate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&language=ja&fromScript=jpan&toScript=latn'
constructed_url = endpoint_var_name + path + params
```

More info on this can be found in the [Quickstart: Use the translator to transliterate text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-transliterate?pivots=programming-language-python).

For more info on the Transliterate API, see the [Translator 3.0: Transliterate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-transliterate) documentation. This shows that the parameters `api-version`, `language`, `fromScript` and `toScript` are all required.

**EDIT:**
I just tested translating (*not* transliterating) from Japanese to English, and that works. At least, if this: `こんにちは` means Hello, it does. Transliterating might not be necessary.

私はこれが役立つことを願っています。

Comment: Thanks @rickvdbosch for your prompt response. I realized the mistake.